# Create a dict form a difficult string format python

Tags: python

Given:

```
str_var = 'host = "s"port = "d"service_name = "a"pass = "b"user = "c"'
```

> Rules to consider : between '""' will always be a simple string with no lenght limitations, the format will always be as described, not other modifications will appear.

Is there a way to create a dict that has the value before '=' as a key and the key value to be the string that is after '=' ends at the second '"'?

Example of result :

```
{'host': 's',
'port' = 'd',
'service_name ': 'a',
'user': 'c'}
```

Comment: What are the rules for that format…? Is it always a single character inside the quotes? May there be quotes inside the quotes? Any other special characters one would need to consider?

Comment: Only rule to consider is that between "" can be a string with no special characters, no qoutes or anything, just a simple string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a regex to capture a key and it's value : `(\w+)\s+=\s+"(\w+)"`
2. Use `re.findall` to get a list of matches  `[('host', 's'), ('port', 'd'), ('service_name', 'a'), ('pass', 'b'), ('user', 'c')]`
3. Finally pass from pairs to a `dict`, just with `dict(pairs)`

```
import re

value = 'host = "s"port = "d"service_name = "a"pass = "b"user = "c"'
pairs = re.findall('(\w+)\s+=\s+"(\w+)"', value)
result = dict(pairs)
print(result) # {'host': 's', 'port': 'd', 'service_name': 'a', 'pass': 'b', 'user': 'c'}
```

Comment: OP still needs to define in more detail what characters are allowed to appear in the string. I suspect that `\w` might not be enough to cover it (although it will work for the example).

Answer (score 0):

First i split the string then i remove the = then i make a dictionary with a loop by giving keys and values.

```
str_var = 'host = "s" port = "d" service_name = "a" pass = "b" user = "c"'
list1 = str_var.split(" ")
for i in list1:
    if i == '=':
        list1.remove(i)
print(list1)
dict1 = {}
for i in range(int(len(list1) / 2)):
    dict1[list1[i]] = list1[i+1]
print(dict1)
```